# Log application event errors to a folder

Tags: asp.net, events, exception, logging

How can I configure my web application so that when it throws an uncaught exception, Windows will log the exception to a folder for my application? Or where would I configure this?

I know I can explicitly log events to wherever I want them to go in my application with code, but I am referring here to the exceptions that the application throws that I didn't catch (or caught and re-threw because I couldn't do anything with it).

EDIT:

What if I wanted to categorize events from applications that I don't control into their own folders. Is that even possible? I'm thinking maybe what I need to do is just code my own event viewer with better filtering capabilities, but it would sure be handy if I could just configure the existing one to work this way.

Comment: You know by default that it writes the errors to the system's event log? If that's not sufficient for you, then install [Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) ([NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/elmah/)) and configure it for XML file logs. I typically make an `~/App_Data/Elmah Errors` folder.

Comment: Right, it's just that it would be helpful if I could go to the folder for a particular application and not have to sift through messages from every application in Windows. We do use Elmah in some of our apps, but not sure whether Elmah works well with WCF services? I'll look into it. But it also seems like there are errors that make it into the event log but never even go through any kind of application events where you could handle/log them.

Comment: I don't know about WCF- I haven't really messed with that.